# Avoid today's day in moment.js

Tags: javascript

In my application, moment.js, gives the today's day if inside moment is an empty array:

```js
 const date = moment([]).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

 console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/moment/moment/2.2.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

How to avoid this, and if inside is an empty array to get the array, but not today's day?

Answer (score 0):

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/

If you pass an array as parameter of moment, it will read it like [year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond]. If you pass an empty array it works like if you didn't send any parameters, so it works like moment() or new Date(), assigning actual date.

If you don't want it to work in this way you can insert a null instead of an empty array and it will be an invalid date, not actual date.

Comment: how to output the date if the date is valid if not to set null, and i made this:  
 `const date = moment([] === undefined ? null : myArray, MM/DD/YYYY), and after that i made: `date.isValid ? myValue : null`,    but it dos not work, and i get just information about that date. How to solve it?

Comment: [] === undefined is going to be false always, you could use myArray.length === 0 as condition